# Showing UIActionSheet over UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uialertview, uiactionsheet

For a specific server notification I am supposed to show an UIActionSheet. But problem here is when that event comes, at the same time if any UIAlertView already showing on any view controller, it make the UIActionSheet disabled( After pressed ok for alert view I am not able to select anything on view controller , view got disabled because of UIActionSheet). Anyone faced this kind of problem, Any idea how to solve it?

I have tried by dismissing alert view before showing action sheet, however which alert view do I need to dismiss as I have many alert view in many controller. All are local to that controllers. How to solve this problem.

**Note:**
Same problem won't come for iPod, as it wont allow to click ok before responding to UIActionSheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a Global Alert view named it as activeAlertView. Now when you show a alert view please check that alert view and then show and assign. Like

declare a property in .h and synthesize it

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIAlertView *activeAlertView;
```

then use the below code when try to show an alert.

```
if(self.activeAlertView){
    [self.activeAlertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
}
UIAlertView *localAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Your message" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil ];
[localAlert show];
self.activeAlertView = localAlert;
[localAlert release];
```

this way your activeAlertview will keep the current aler view's reference and before show the actionSheet dismiss the alert view.

Comment: make a similar global alert view in you child view controller and use same logic like if there is an alert dismiss it, show a new alert and keep its reference in global variable. Importantly you have the access the child view controller's global property.

Comment: Ya thats my last option... I have been trying any other possibilities to handle this case... I'll update if any thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For Identified which `alert-view` you must set **Tag** or `alert-view`.

**Ex:-**

```
alertviewName.tag=1;
```

Then you can check is there alert-view Open in Particular `view-controller` `sub-views` use bellow code like:-

```
- (BOOL) doesAlertViewExist {

        for (UIView* view in yuorviewcontroller.view.subviews) {
            BOOL alert = [view isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]];

            if (alert)
            {
             return YES;
            }

        }
       return NO;

}
```

After this method called you get BOOL value YES or NO If Yes then dismiss it using UIAlertview's Delegate:-

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
```

and put your Actionsheet appear code into `didDismissWithButtonIndex` method.

Answer (score 0):

When the message comes, first *check* if there is an alert view.

Show the action sheet *after* the alert view is dismissed. In `didDismiss...` you can check a BOOL flag if you now have to show the action sheet or not.

Comment: Ya I got your point, but the problem is which alert view do I need to dismiss... Parent view controller is receiving the server event and it is displaying the action sheet also.. but before that in any child view controller alert view might have shown.. how do I know which alert view and how to dismiss.. Do I need to send message to all child?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you should use

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

method rather than,

```
 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

so your code wil be:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if (buttonIndex == 0)
{
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = ...
    [actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Its an incoming call notification... I can't wait to click the ok button of UIAlertview, I need to show the action sheet by giving high priority.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
      for (UIWindow* w in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows)
      {
           for (NSObject* obj in w.subviews)
           { 
                if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]])
                {
                    [(UIAlertView*)obj dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:[(UIAlertView*)obj
                cancelButtonIndex] animated:YES];
                }
           }
       }