# in IOS7, how to check whether an UIAlertView exist in window ？

Tags: ios7

before IOS7, i check it use this method：

```
UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]; 

if ([window.subviews count] > 0) {

    for (UIView *alertView in window.subviews) {  

        if ([alertView isKindOfClass:[UIAlertView class]]) {

            NSLog(@"it is alertView!");       
        }    
    } 
}
```

but, in IOS7, it does not work, how should i do now;

Comment: this one work ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17271862/showing-uiactionsheet-over-uialertview

Comment: @Smick someone tell me that UIAlertView did not be added to any windows in IOS7 SDK

Comment: If you want to check if any alert is showed check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702565/find-uialertview-without-having-reference-to-it-ios-7/19275311#19275311